# Question about Bayesian probabilities. Where did I go wrong?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, bayesian

I was solving a question for an acquaintance, about probabilties. The original question goes like this:

> Of all threats in an year, $12\%$ are Tier 1 and the remaining $88\%$ are Tier 2. If the probability that a reported Tier 1 threat is actually a Tier 2 is $21\%$ and the probability that a reported Tier 2 threat is actually a Tier 1 is $33\%$, then what is the probability that a reported Tier 1 is actually a Tier 1?

---

Here are my attempts to solve;

> Let probability that an event is **Tier 1**$=P(T_1)=12\%$
>
> Let probability that an event is **Tier 2**$=P(T_2)=88\%$
>
> Let probability that a reported **Tier 1** was actually **Tier 2**$=P(M_{1\to2})=21\%$
>
> Let probability that a reported **Tier 2** was actually **Tier 1**$=P(M_{2\to1})=33\%$
>
> Let there be $10000$ events.

...

> Then,
>
> $\#T_1=1200$
>
> $\#T_2=8800$

...

> Let the number of reported **Tier 1** events be $O$.
>
> Let the number of reported **Tier 2** events be $T$.

...

> Then,
>
> Number of actual **Tier 1** Events from number of reported **Tier 1** events $={{(100-21)}\over100}\times O=O_1$
>
> Number of actual **Tier 2** Events from number of reported **Tier 1** events $={{21}\over100}\times O=T_1$
>
> Number of actual **Tier 1** Events from number of reported **Tier 2** events $={{33}\over100}\times T=O_2$
>
> Number of actual **Tier 2** Events from number of reported **Tier 2** events $={{(100-33)}\over100}\times T=T_2$

...

> Since,
>
> Number of **Tier 1** threats $=1200$
>
> $O_1+O_2=1200$
>
> So $\left({{(100-21)}\over100}\times O\right)+\left({{33}\over100}\times T\right)=1200$
>
> Since,
>
> Number of **Tier 2** threats $=8800$
>
> $T_1+T_2=8800$
>
> So $\left({{21}\over100}\times O\right)+\left({{(100-33)}\over100}\times T\right)=8800$

From here I get two equations in $O$ and $T$,

$\left({{79}\over100}\times O\right)+\left({{33}\over100}\times T\right)=1200$

and

$\left({{21}\over100}\times O\right)+\left({{67}\over100}\times T\right)=8800$

Wolfram|Alpha reports that $O$ is negative.

How is this possible? Where did I go wrong?

---

The actual question is near the middle [here](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/9794740/1/Pokemon-The-Origin-of-Species).

The answer should be explainable in a text-only environment.

Comment: There is no such question in the linked fanfiction.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Last chapter, middle. The portion about Tyranitar rampages.

Answer (score 2):

Using **conditional probability** expressions in a **Bayesian probability** question will lead to *much less* confusion about the topic.

Use $T_1,T_2$ as the *mutually exclusive and exhaustive* events that a threat is tier 1 or tier 2 respectively, and $R_1,R_2$ as the m.e.e. events that a threat is reported as such.

> Of all threats in an year, $12\%$ are Tier 1 and the remaining $88\%$ are Tier 2. If the probability that a reported Tier 1 threat is actually a Tier 2 is $21\%$ and the probability that a reported Tier 2 threat is actually a Tier 1 is $33\%$, then what is the probability that a reported Tier 1 is actually a Tier 1?

So, you are told :

- $\mathsf P(T_1)=0.12$ the probability that an event is actually tier 1
- $\mathsf P(T_2)=0.88$ the probability that an event is actually tier 2
- $\mathsf P(T_2\mid R_1)=0.21$ the probability that an event is tier 2 given that it is reported as tier 1.
- $\mathsf P(T_1\mid R_2)=0.33$ the probability that an event is tier 1 given that it is reported as tier 2.

You seek $\mathsf P(T_1\mid R_1)$, the probability that a threat is tier 1 given that it is reported as tier 1.

> $\mathsf P(T_1\mid R_1)=1-\mathsf P(T_2\mid R_1)$.

Comment: So you mean $0.12\times0.79+0.88\times0.33=0.3852$?

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo No.  That is $\mathsf P(T_1)\mathsf P(T_1\mid R_1)+\mathsf P(T_2)\mathsf P(T_1\mid R_@)$ which is meaningless.

Comment: Then? The Bayes equation on Wikipedia?

Comment: LOL. In a Bayesian question with this setup, you'd just assume that they'd be asking for a $P(R|T)$. I think the people asking the question might have asked the wrong thing here. Good job reading the question carefully!

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

- All actual threats are reported threats.$\\[4pt]$

  All reported threats are actual threats.

In other words, all actual (assessed) threats are first reported. Also, there are no false alarms. If a threat is reported at any tier level, then it is later assessed as an actual threat at some tier level.

Let the sample space be the set of pairs $(i,j)$ of reported threats, where $i \in \{1,2\}$ is the tier level reported, and $j \in \{1,2\}$ is the assessed (actual) tier level.

Let $p(i,j)$ be the probability of the event $\{(i,j)\}$.

Let $a=p(1,1),\;b=p(1,2),\;c=p(2,1),\;d=p(2,2)$.

Let $R_i$ be the event that tier level $i$ is reported.

Let $T_j$ be the event that tier level $j$ is assessed.

The goal is to find $P(T_1|R_1) = {\displaystyle{\frac{a}{a+b}}}$.

From the given information we get the following equations
\begin{align*}
P(T_1) &=  a + c = \frac{12}{100}\\[4pt]
P(T_2) &= b+ d  = \frac{88}{100}\\[4pt]
P(T_2|R_1) &= \frac{b}{a+b} = \frac{21}{100}\\[4pt]
P(T_1|R_2) &= \frac{c}{c+d} = \frac{33}{100}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
After clearing denominators on the last two equations, we have a system of $4$ linear equations in $4$ unknowns, which yields the solutions
$$
a = -\frac{1659}{4600}
,\;\;
b = -\frac{441}{4600}
,\;\;
c = \frac{2211}{4600}
,\;\;
d = \frac{4489}{4600}
$$
If we temporily ignore the obvious issue (negative values of $a,b$), we get
$$P(T1|R1) = \frac{a}{a+b} = \frac{79}{100}$$
but of course, we can't have $a,b < 0$, so unless I made a logical or algebraic error, the problem is wrong.

Comment: I had thought that the problem was wrong, however, I couldn't find out what. Is there a formula such that given the probability $x$ that a tier 1 was reported as tier 2, we can find out the probability $y$ that a tier 2 was reported as tier 1? Anything similar?

Comment: Assume the value of $x$ is given. Using the $4$ equations in my posted answer, if you replace $33/100$ by the value $x$, and replace $21/100$ by the unknown $y$, you would have a system of $4$ linear equations in $5$ unknowns, so you would not be able to solve for $y$.

Comment: Hmm. That is Bleak.

Answer (score 0):

12% of population is Tier 1 and will be reported as such 79% of the time. So, True Tier 1 reports will be (0.12)(0.79) * population.
88% of population is Tier 2 but will be reported as Tier 1 33% of the time. So false Tier 1 reports will be (0.88)(0.33) * population.
Probability of true Tier1 report is (true Tier 1 reports)/(all Tier 1 reports):
(.12)(.79)/((.12)(.79)+(.88)(.33) = .246106

Probably more clear using the 10000 threats and reports example from the question:
0.12*10000=1200 actual Tier 1
    0.79*1200=948 actual Tier 1s reported as 1s:TRUE Tier 1 reports
    0.21*1200=252 actual 1s reported as 2s: FALSE Tier 2 reports
  0.88*10000=8800 actual Tier 2
    0.67*8800=5896 actual 2s reported as 2s:    TRUE Tier 2 reports
    0.33*8800=2904 actual 2s reported as 1s:    FALSE Tier 1 reports

All Tier 1 reports = TRUE + FALSE Tier 1 reports: 948+2904=3852

Probability that reported Tier 1 is actual Tier 1
  (TRUE 1 reports)/(All 1 reports) =948/3852=0.246

Comment: "$12$% of population is Tier 1 and will be reported as such $79$% of the time." Isn't that saying $P(R_1|T_1) = .79$?

Comment: You forget that there are some reported tier 2s that are actually Tier 1s.